# Bootstrap Modal: Building a dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to put a specific content into the Bootstrap modal without repeating the code.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text1">Text1</li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text2">Text2</li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text3">Text3</li>
</ul>
```

So that means the modal should be smart enough to understand which item (Text1, Text2 or Text3) was clicked and show its content which is stored in attribute data-content.

How can I do this?

Comment: It tells you how to do this on the Bootstrap Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Comment: have you read the section [varying modal content with a trigger](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal body will be the `data-content` attribute value of clicked `li` element.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$("li[data-target='#myModal']").on('click',function(){
  $(".modal-body").html($(this).attr('data-content'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text1">Text1</li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text2">Text2</li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text3">Text3</li>
</ul>
```